# cUrl dont work after php upgrade

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Can someone please help me on this, my sites cUrl process is not working after php update. it was working perfect before. code i used is as follows:

```
function checkBadge($url,$id,$uid) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;

$mystring = $data;
$findme = '/media/badges/badge_';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "ERROR!";
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE db_punched_blogs SET verified = '1' WHERE uid='$uid' AND id='$id'";
    $q = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
   if($q){
       echo 'OK';
   }
   else{
       mysql_error();
   }
}
}
```

$pos always returns false.

Version of php and libcurl i use as per phpinfo() is :
PHP : Version 5.3.29
Previous Version was PHP 4.4.4
cUrl: Version 7.35.0

Comment: Any specific reason not to use `if(!$pos){` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if(!$pos)  like @RAZERZ said. If still now working, try to print_r() each step with exit();. So that you can find out what each step produce.

Comment: Hmmm... I asked this question long back... Nyway thanks for your time